# .map ruby statement not displaying as I expect

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, string, dictionary

I have a has many join table and displaying data based on that table.  The data has been mapped and I have confirmed the classes of the variable as being a string.

However in the actual table it displays the mapped values in my returned html as ["String"]

For example

```
 <td><%= lead.case_details.map{|case_detail| case_detail.case_type} %></td>

Displays ["AC Suit on Account"]
```

Also I attempted to just split the string by calling case_detail.case_type[2..-2] and get this

```
[" Suit on Accou"]
```

My other rows in the same table that are called directly on the model are showing up normal

```
<td><%= lead.city.titlecase %></td>
```

Displays

```
Cityville
```

In IRB I get this

```
>> case_detail.case_type
=> "AC Suit on Account"
>> case_detail.case_type.class
=> String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-join)

```
lead.case_details.map(&:case_type).join ','
# "AC Suit on Account, Some other case_type, yet another case_type"
```